# Find and remove common part of two strings and remove it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need some advices how to find and remove common part of two strings.

My (not allways working) code:

```
var link = $('.some a').attr('href');
window.location.hash = link.replace(window.location.url, '');
```

Script should add the link after '#' in AJAX to give users the possibility of linking to a specific article in website (when document is ready another script will check is something after root url and when it's necessary load content dynamically).

But problem is that, the links not always contain 'http://' or domain name and I would like to prevent duplicate domain name after #, I would also like to work on different domains and folders.

For e.q. link contains string: '/joomla-folder/index.php/ssome-article-name'
and the `window.location.url` is 'http://mydomain.com/joomla-folder/'

The /xxx/ is the sub folder where joomla is installed.

The result what I want to achieve is to create string looking in this way:
'index.php/ssome-article-name' (and next is the part which I've got now) and use `window.location.hash` to get url like this: http://mydomain.com/joomla-folder/#/index.php/ssome-article-name and when clitent type url like this use `replace('#/','')` to create url which I will pass to AJAX function.

Answer (score 0):

ok in my case I used something like this and it's working for me:

```
var linkPreHash = window.location.href.split('/');
var linkToReplace = $(this).attr('href');
for(var i = 0; i < linkPreHash.length; i++){                
    linkToReplace = linkToReplace.replace(linkPreHash[i], "");
    if(i == linkPreHash.length-1){
        window.location.hash = linkToReplace.replace('//','');
    }
}
```